# How do I fix the error 403 I am getting with XAMPP while I am using mod_userdir?

Tags: arch-linux, permissions, webserver, xampp

I am running Arch Linux and I decided to use XAMPP so I can create and test web pages. Anyway, I followed the instructions given in the site and extracted it to `/opt/lampp` and I also uncommented the line in `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf` so `mod_userdir` will be enabled.

Now, when I try to access my user `public_html` (via http://localhost/~user), I get this error:

```
Access forbidden!

    You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either 
    read-protected or not readable by the server.

    If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
```

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 5):

You need to make the public_html and the files there readable by the web server.

One way is to run `chmod o+x /home/user` (allow everyone to switch to the home directory)
and `chmod -R o+rX /home/user/public_html` (make public_html and files there readable by everyone).

If you need better access controls, use ACLs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this

```
<Directory "/Users/*/Sites">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

make sure you use `Require all granted` instead of

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

when using apache >2.4

Comment: This did the trick. But I wonder why this is not in any of the tutorials I found. And what does "Require all granted" even mean?

Answer (score 1):

The default `httpd.conf` file makes all directories unavailable:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

You need to configure Apache to allow access to your directory(s):

```
<Directory "/srv/httpd/htdocs">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

That's at a minimum.  You might have to do some other things. Get the 403 response, then look in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` (or wherever XAMPP puts it) to see what went on.